# Where should I install bootloader in a system with multiple disks?

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader

I have selected partitions for root, home, and a swap area.

I have two drives, one for storage, one for the operating systems (ssd, soon to be systems). Should I install the boot loader on the drive with windows or not? And will it overwrite the OS?

The SSD contains the following:

```
/dev/sdb (ATA Samsung SSD 840 (120.0GB))
/dev/sdb1 (Windows 7 (loader))
/dev/sdb2 (Windows OS Partition)
/dev/sdb5 (Ubuntu OS Partition)
```

/home and swap area are on the storage drive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, install them in `/dev/sdb`.

`sdb` contains all of your OSes and boot files, so it is the better choice. However, it really does not matter. GRUB works fine across disks, so you can install it to the other drive if you really want. I recommend an install to `sdb` though just for simplicity and ease-of-maintainence later on (esp. if you need to re-install GRUB).

It is really your choice. It works anywhere, but I recommend that you place it on the `/dev/sdb` disk.

Comment: It works, and grub is the bootloader and Windows 7 and Ubuntu are displayed, however upon booting into Windows no usb ports work.

Comment: @AricLeather That is an unrelated issue. I blame Windows.

Comment: Yeah... If I uninstall all the drivers in devmgmt and reboot into Windows it works. After going back Ubuntu they stop working in Windows again. I'll do more research on it. I don't plan on using Windows much, so its not a big deal. Thanks for the help.